# PDO::FETCH_OBJ + custom classes?

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

When I `fetchAll()` query results (`SELECT * FROM users ...`) as an array of objects, I want these objects to be of a certain class, namely `User`.

1. How do I force PDO to use the data type `User` for the result objects, and
2. do I have to define all member variables corresponding to the field names in the class?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

there is a static field to tell PDO to fetch into a class, `PDO::FETCH_CLASS`.

Here is an example of getting `User` objects;

```
class User {
    public $name;
    public $firstname;
}
```

You have to ensure that the field names are same as the column ones and that the class is accessible from the class / file you're working from. (`SELECT *` works too, just have all fields available)

```
$query = "SELECT name, firstname FROM users";
```

And to wrap it in classes, use the next,

```
$users = $sth->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_CLASS, "User");
```

Then you can simply access it as an array of `User` objects.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at http://www.php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.setfetchmode.php
Setting the fetch mode to FETCH_CLASS should get you on your way.

Edit: KarelG beat me to it ;)